# How to add a colored box to the left of the title and introduction box

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to insert a blue box to the left of the "Solve 4 Success" and "Member" text. I'm trying to have them directly on top of each other, with the textbox to the left. Here is an image if my explanation is confusing.[image] Let me know if you can help. I'm new to HTML and CSS so anything could help. Thanks

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  src: url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'tekoregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'playfair_displayregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'poppinsmedium';
  src: url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
*{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    border:0px;
}
.topnav {
    background-color: rgb(84,104,217);
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: 'futuralight';
    font-weight:900;
 }
  .topnav a {
    float: left;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 21px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 19px;
    position: relative;
    left:2%;
  }
  .topnav a:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 84%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 6px;
    left: 8%;
    background-color: white;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  }
 .topnav a:hover:before {
    visibility: visible;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
.topnav a.active-menu:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 84%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom:6px;
    left: 8%;
    background-color: white;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s; 
    }
  .bigcomser{
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 80px;
  }
.bodycs{
  background-color:  #EEF0FC;
  height:8000px;
}
.comser{
  font-family: 'tekoregular';
  padding-top:42px;
  font-family: 'playfair_displayregular';
  font-weight:900;
}
.abtcomser{
  padding-top: 48px;
  padding-bottom: 28px;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  left:10%;
  width:80%;
}
.s4s{
  position: relative;
  left:10%;
  margin-top:60px;
  height:350px;
  width:80%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow:
  0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034),
  0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048),
  0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06),
  0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072),
  0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086),
  0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.s4simage{
  width:38.3%;
  position: absolute;
  right:0%;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
}
.s4stitle{
  position: relative;
  left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
  color:rgb(84,104,217);
  font-weight:900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
}
.s4slink{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:rgb(84,104,217);
}
.titles4s{
  padding-top:2px;
  font-size:22px;
  padding-left:4%;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  font-weight:300;
}
.s4sparagraph{
  width:55%;
  position: relative;
  left:4%;
  font-size:17px;
  top:60px;  
  font-family: 'futuralight';
}
.bluebox{
  background-color: rgb(84,104,217);
  padding-top: 80px;
  width:2%;
  position: relative;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="../CSS/stylecomser.css" />
    <title>Community Service</title>
</head>
<body class='bodycs'>
    <header class="topnav" id="topnav">
        <a class="link" href="../index.html">Home</a>
        <a class="link" href="#Academics">Academics</a>
        <a class="link" href="#Projects">Projects</a>
        <a class="active-menu" href="../Pages/communityservice.html">Community Service</a>
      </header>
      <div class='bigcomser'>
        <p class='comser'>
            Community Service
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class='abtcomser'>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisici
            ng elit. Dicta, libero! Recusandae provident est quam quisquam.
             Sequi itaque suscipit tempore corrupti officia maxime 
             nihil consequatur perspiciatis repellat placeat sed, voluptatum vitae.lor
             em Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro similique, prov
             ident libero laudantium amet odit unde dolor eaque earum qui impedit possimus natus est
              distinctio commodi quod aut numquam temporibus?
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class='s4s'>
        <img class='s4simage' src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg" alt="Missing File">
        <p class='s4stitle'>
            <a class='s4slink' href="https://www.solve4success.org" target="_blank">Solve 4 Success</a>
        </p>
        <div class='bluebox'>
        </div>
        <p class='titles4s'>
            Member
        </p>
        <p class='s4sparagraph'>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetu
            r adipisicing elit. Eaque minus ab doloribus nulla quidem esse re
            pellat, asperiores ex vero minima saepe. Est officia accusamus odio et ver
            itatis placeat sapiente laudantium?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 
            consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nesciunt blanditiis alias officiis ducimus tenetur, ipsa moll
            itia dicta error aliquam aliquid aperiam est repellat iure vitae
            bum exercitationem nihil, accusam
            us libero.
        </p>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried using border-left on the container itself ?

Comment: Can I do that, and limit the size and placement of the border?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replaced your `.bluebox` to a `::before` element with `position: absolute;`. And placed `.s4slink` and `.titles4s` in `.s4stitle`. Now the height of the left line will be a sum of both titles height. Look please.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  src: url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'tekoregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'playfair_displayregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'poppinsmedium';
  src: url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
*{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    border:0px;
}
.topnav {
    background-color: rgb(84,104,217);
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: 'futuralight';
    font-weight:900;
 }
  .topnav a {
    float: left;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 21px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 19px;
    position: relative;
    left:2%;
  }
  .topnav a:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 84%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 6px;
    left: 8%;
    background-color: white;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  }
 .topnav a:hover:before {
    visibility: visible;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
.topnav a.active-menu:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 84%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom:6px;
    left: 8%;
    background-color: white;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s; 
    }
  .bigcomser{
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 80px;
  }
.bodycs{
  background-color:  #EEF0FC;
  height:8000px;
}
.comser{
  font-family: 'tekoregular';
  padding-top:42px;
  font-family: 'playfair_displayregular';
  font-weight:900;
}
.abtcomser{
  padding-top: 48px;
  padding-bottom: 28px;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  left:10%;
  width:80%;
}
.s4s{
  position: relative;
  left:10%;
  margin-top:60px;
  height:350px;
  width:80%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow:
  0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034),
  0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048),
  0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06),
  0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072),
  0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086),
  0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.s4simage{
  width:38.3%;
  position: absolute;
  right:0%;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
}
.s4stitle{
  position: relative;
  left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
  color:rgb(84,104,217);
  font-weight:900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
}
.s4stitle::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84,104,217);
  width:10px;
  height: 100%;
  position:absolute;
  left: -4%; 
  top: 30px; /* = padding-top of parent */
}
.s4slink{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:rgb(84,104,217);
}
.titles4s{
  padding-top:2px;
  font-size:22px;
  padding-left:4%;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  font-weight:300;
}
.s4sparagraph{
  width:55%;
  position: relative;
  left:4%;
  font-size:17px;
  top:60px;  
  font-family: 'futuralight';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="../CSS/stylecomser.css" />
    <title>Community Service</title>
</head>
<body class='bodycs'>
    <header class="topnav" id="topnav">
        <a class="link" href="../index.html">Home</a>
        <a class="link" href="#Academics">Academics</a>
        <a class="link" href="#Projects">Projects</a>
        <a class="active-menu" href="../Pages/communityservice.html">Community Service</a>
      </header>
      <div class='bigcomser'>
        <p class='comser'>
            Community Service
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class='abtcomser'>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisici
            ng elit. Dicta, libero! Recusandae provident est quam quisquam.
             Sequi itaque suscipit tempore corrupti officia maxime 
             nihil consequatur perspiciatis repellat placeat sed, voluptatum vitae.lor
             em Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro similique, prov
             ident libero laudantium amet odit unde dolor eaque earum qui impedit possimus natus est
              distinctio commodi quod aut numquam temporibus?
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class='s4s'>
        <img class='s4simage' src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg" alt="Missing File">
        <p class='s4stitle'>
            <a class='s4slink' href="https://www.solve4success.org" target="_blank">Solve 4 Success</a>
            <p class='titles4s'>
            Member
            </p>
        </p>
        
        <p class='s4sparagraph'>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetu
            r adipisicing elit. Eaque minus ab doloribus nulla quidem esse re
            pellat, asperiores ex vero minima saepe. Est officia accusamus odio et ver
            itatis placeat sapiente laudantium?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 
            consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nesciunt blanditiis alias officiis ducimus tenetur, ipsa moll
            itia dicta error aliquam aliquid aperiam est repellat iure vitae
            bum exercitationem nihil, accusam
            us libero.
        </p>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```